# NSString Range or Index out of bounds

Tags: cocoa, nsstring

For some reason this is tripping me up today.

I've got an NSString I'm trying to search using `-rangeOfString:options:range:` and I keep getting this exception. What I'm doing:

I'm searching the string trying to find the next newline character after a certain character index (so, given an index `i`, find the next occurrence of `@"\n"` after that). I have `i`, now I'm searching for the next newline like so (this is in an `NSTextView` subclass)

```
NSRange untilReturn = [wholeString rangeOfString:@"\n" options:kNilOptions range:NSMakeRange(startLocation, [wholeString length] - 1)];
```

Where `wholeText` is the whole text of the textView and `startLocation` is `i`.

But when I run this I get an out of bounds exception and I can't seem to figure out what's going wrong. Can someone lend a hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple! In my particular case, I was much better off using the method `-lineRangeForRange:`. I'd totally forgotten about that API. So the code looks like the following:

```
NSRange lineRange = [wholeString lineRangeForRange:originalRange];
NSString *lineString = [wholeString substringWithRange:lineRange];
```

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter to `NSMakeRange` is the *length* (from the first parameter). Unless `startLocation` is always 0 (and I assume it's not), your length is going to be too long. You actually want the second parameter to be `[wholeString length] - startLocation`).

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense but I'm still getting the exception.

Comment: @teh1 yes I have. Sometimes it works and other times it doesn't. Leads me to think something else is messed up. But it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking in the right place? According to the docs  `rangeOfString:options:range:` should never throw an `NSOutOfBoundsException`, but an `NSRangeException` instead. Do you have exception breakpoints enabled and did you follow the exception to the exact line of code?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. The exception is `-[NSBigMutableString substringWithRange:]: Range or index out of bounds`

Comment: Is there any chance you can echo and edit in the values of all the associated variables? `wholeString`,`startLocation`?